# Srcset rendering image in wrong size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-images, srcset

I'm trying to deliver responsive/adaptive images based on device width.

Original image:

```
<img src="https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png"/>
```

With Srcset:

```
<img
      src="https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png"
      srcset="
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=400   400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=800   800w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=1400 1400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=2000 2000w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=3800 3800w
      "
/>
```

I'm facing two issues:

1) Even on a smaller device (like iPhone 6s), the image of width 2000px is loaded (it should load 800px image).

2) I've placed both images (with and without srcset) together. Both of them loaded the image with the same dimensions. However, the one with srcset is rendered small compared to others. Since no width is specified in html/css, it should render in the width of the actual image, right? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfcbatdn/

Answer (score 0):

With `srcset` `attribute` you have to provide `sizes` `attribute` make responsive image. Change like this.

```
<img
      src="https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png"
      srcset="
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=400   400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=800   800w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=1400 1400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=2000 2000w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=3800 3800w
      "
/>
```

To

```
<img
      src="https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png"
      srcset="
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=400   400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=800   800w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=1400 1400w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=2000 2000w,
        https://cdn.statically.io/img/www.forexadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Exness-Affiliate.png?w=3800 3800w
      "
      sizes="(max-width: 991px) 480px,(max-width: 1024px) 800px,(max-width: 1920px) 1400px,(max-width: 2560px) 2000px,3800px"
/>
```

Change `sizes` attribute `max-width=?` your desire `@media` Query. Also you have to add `meta view port` inside `<head></head>` tag. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`.

More details in [Responsive Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the second issue I mentioned still remains. See https://jsfiddle.net/ntjfwecy/

I also tried generating responsive images using https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/. The 'sizes' it added is only `(max-width: 728px) 100vw, 728px`